# delete only lines after match1 up to match2

Tags: python

I have checked and played with various examples and it appears that my problem is a bit more complex than what I have been able to find. What I need to do is search for a particular string and then delete the following line and keep deleting lines until another string is found. So an example would be the following:

```
a
b
color [
0 0 0,
1 1 1,
3 3 3,
] #color
y
z
```

Here, `"color ["` is match1, and `"] #color"` is match2. So then what is desired is the following:

```
a
b
color [
] #color
y
z
```

Comment: It would be helpful to identify what is "match1" and "match2" and also provide some corresponding output for your input shown. And any other constraints (could also be shown by input/output pairs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "simple to follow" code example will get you started .. you can tweak it as needed. Note that it processes the file line-by-line, so this will work with any size file.

```
start_marker = 'startdel'
end_marker = 'enddel'

with open('data.txt') as inf:
    ignoreLines = False
    for line in inf:
        if start_marker in line:
            print line,
            ignoreLines = True
        if end_marker in line:
            ignoreLines = False            
        if not ignoreLines:
            print line,
```

It uses `startdel` and `enddel` as "markers" for starting and ending the ignoring of data.

*Update*:

Modified code based on a request in the comments, this *will* now include/print the lines that contain the "markers".

Given this input data (borrowed from @drewk):

```
Beginning of the file...
stuff
startdel
   delete this line
   delete this line also
enddel
stuff as well
the rest of the file...
```

it yields:

```
Beginning of the file...
stuff
startdel
enddel
stuff as well
the rest of the file...
```

Comment: This worked fantastic, but I need to keep the search lines 'look for this line' and 'until this line is found'.  The code currently removes these lines also.  Is it a simple modification?

Comment: @ScottRichardson I updated the code, give it a whirl and see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Hi Levon, I tried the new code and for me it prints the 'enddel' line twice.

Comment: @ScottRichardson Posting your data is useful. The problem is that your starting and ending "markers" are similar .. the start is found by checking for `"find me"` in the string. Unfortunately, your end marker also contains `"find me"` as part of it. You can see the problem disappears if you change your end marker to something else, like `"find too"` (ie something that is not also "find me"). What sort of "markers" will the data you are using have?

Comment: Ahh, ok. I can't answer that until tomorrow because I don't have access to the file until then, and I don't recall what the exact string is from memory. Will your code sweep the whole file?  Because I have up to 20 occurrences of this same type in the file that it would have to take out.

Comment: Yes that is correct and yes I see what you mean. Hopefully it's a non-issue but I can't know until tomorrow.  I'll follow up as soon as I know. Thanks much for staying with it/me! :)

Comment: Hi Levon, I update the original post with what's actually in the file.  But I have discovered that I need some type of 'if' statement for when the code gets to match1.  So the deleting should only take place if the following line has "0 0 0,".  If there is anything else following the match1 line it should move on to the next occurrence.

Comment: @ScottRichardson The problem is still not well defined, and the question keeps changing. At this point I think it is evolving into another question (e.g., now we have to consider data *after* the start marker) that should refined and posted separately. I think you got a number of solutions for your original question. (Also, when editing your original posts, it would good to keep still relevant information in the post as not everyone coming to the question will know what was there before :)

Comment: Hi Levon, fair enough.  I am new to this format and obviously making a lot of mistakes which won't happen again.  So my apologies.  I tried your code on my actual file and it works unbelievably fast, approx. 1 second, and it does the job except for the needed 'if' statement.  Would it be OK then to post a new question, with your code as the starting point?  Thank you!

Comment: @ScottRichardson I made a final edit to the code making it easier to modif (you can set the start/end markers at the top)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single regex by using nongreedy `*`.  E.g., assuming you want to keep both the `"look for this line"` and the `"until this line is found"` lines, and discard only the lines in between, you could do:

```
>>> my_regex = re.compile("(look for this line)"+
...                       ".*?"+ # match as few chars as possible
...                       "(until this line is found)",
...                       re.DOTALL)
>>> new_str = my_regex.sub("\1\2", old_str)
```

A few notes:

- The `re.DOTALL` flag tells Python that "." can match newlines -- by default it matches any character except a newline
- The parentheses define "numbered match groups", which are then used later when I say "\1\2" to make sure that we *don't* discard the first and last line.  If you did want to discard either or both of those, then just get rid of the \1 and/or the \2.  E.g., to keep the first but not the last use `my_regex.sub("\1", old_str)`; or to get rid of both use `my_regex.sub("", old_str)`

For further explanation, see: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html or search for "non-greedy regular expression" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Hi Edward, this worked perfectly, thank you very much! Although I tried this on a mockup test file, I won't be able to try it on the actual file(s) until tomorrow. It turns out that the files I'll be using this on will be quite large (>100k lines), and there will be up to 20 chunks of deletions that will have to be made. So my question is would this code be the most efficient for a file with many lines, and will this code perform this action until eof is found? Thank you again.

Comment: This will replace all occurrences.  But if your file is very large, then this might not be the best approach, since you'll need to read in the entire file, process it, and then write out the result.  So you might want to use an approach more like the one Levon suggested.  (On modern systems, loading a 100k line file into memory is not beyond reason, but it's certainly not the most efficient approach.)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
s="""Beginning of the file...
stuff
look for this line
   delete this line
   delete this line also
until this line is found
stuff as well
the rest of the file...  """

import re

print re.sub(r'(^look for this line$).*?(^until this line is found$)',
            r'\1\n\2',s,count=1,flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

prints:

```
Beginning of the file...
stuff
look for this line
until this line is found
stuff as well
the rest of the file...
```

You can also use list slices to do this:

```
mStart='look for this line'
mStop='until this line is found'
li=s.split('\n')
print '\n'.join(li[0:li.index(mStart)+1]+li[li.index(mStop):])
```

Same output.

I like `re` for this (being a Perl guy at heart...)